# Simple Generic Function in Kotlin Fails

Tags: generics, kotlin

Here's a simple generic function in Kotlin:

```
fun <T> twice(x: T) : T { return 2 * x }
```

Attempting to build this (either in a project or REPL) results in the following errors:

```
error: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final operator fun times(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int
fun <T> twice(x: T) : T { return 2 * x }
                                   ^
```

If I switch the return statement operands to x * 2, the error messages become:

```
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigDecimal.times(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
fun <T> twice(x: T) : T { return x * 2 }
                                   ^
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `T` could be anything, the compiler is not able to find a matching `times` operator. As you can see in the error message, for `Int`, there a multiple alternatives available

```
public final operator fun times(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun times(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int
```

But unfortunately there's no generic `times` function, which can be used with e.g. `Number`. I'm afraid in this case, you would have to create an overload for each type you want to be handling, i.e., `Double`, `Int`, etc.

Comment: The equivalent template function in C++,

template<class T>
T twice(T x) {
    return 2*x;
}

works as one would expect. So as it currently stands, Kotlin generics cannot do math on the generic type. Interesting.